# Searching on class names with a space (\s) Python lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I wonder if anybody can help :)

I am using python lxml and cssselector to scrape data from HTML pages.

I can select most classes with ease using this method and find it very convenient but I am having a problem selecting class names with a space

For example I want to extract Blah from the following class:

```
<li class="feature height">Blah blah</li>
```

I have tried using the following css selectors without success - whole path is not included as this is not the problem

```
li.feature.height
li.feature height
li.feature:height
```

Anybody know how to do this? I can't find the answer and am sure it must be a fairly common thing that people need to do...

I cannot just select the parent element

```
li.feature
```

as the data is not in the same order on different pages, same applies for nth element selections...

Scratching my head on this a while now and searched alot, hope somebody knows!

I can work around it by getting the data using re's and that works but I wonder if there is a simple solution...

Thanks for you help in advance!

Matt

Extra information as requested - it doesn't work because it returns an empty list or a negative result for boolean

so if use the

```
css_9_seed_height = 'html body div.seedicons ul li.feature.height'

# 9. Get seed_height
seed_height_obj = root.cssselect(css_9_seed_height)
print seed_height_obj
```

This returns an empty list - ie the class is not found but its there

You can assume that root.cssselect() works correctly as I am retrieving lots of other info in the same way

Comment: This isn't a class name with a space, this is two classes. `li.feature.height` should work. Could you provide a more complete example of how it doesn't?

Comment: added to the bottom of post, does this help...?

Comment: I have just tried again and it seems to be working now!